# Socket connection sends one message but not anymore

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcp

I am trying a basic project on Socket connections. I have created the following form:

[image]

The task is quite simple. I am going to send message from the left and then receive from the right.

My code is as follows:

```
private bool _senderStarted = false;
private bool _listenerStarted = false;

private Socket sListener;
private ManualResetEvent listenerNotifier = new ManualResetEvent(false);

private Socket sSender;
private IPEndPoint senderEndpoint = null;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create sockets
    sListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sSender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
}
private void btnSenderStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _senderStarted = true;
    btnSenderStart.Enabled = false;
    btnSenderStop.Enabled = true;
    txtMessage.Enabled = true;
    btnSend.Enabled = true;
    txtMessage.Clear();
    txtMessage.Focus();
    lstSender.Items.Clear();
     // Create sender endpoint
    string[] arr = txtSenderIP.Text.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    byte[] ips = arr.Select(x => byte.Parse(x)).ToArray();
    IPAddress senderAddress = new IPAddress(ips);
    senderEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(senderAddress, (int)txtSenderPort.Value);
    sSender.Connect(senderEndpoint);
}
private void btnListenerStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _listenerStarted = true;
    btnListenerStart.Enabled = false;
    btnListenerStop.Enabled = true;
    lstListener.Items.Clear();
    // Create listener endpoint
    string[] arr = txtListenerIP.Text.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    byte[] ips = arr.Select(x => byte.Parse(x)).ToArray();
    IPAddress listenerAddress = new IPAddress(ips);
    IPEndPoint listenerEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(listenerAddress, (int)txtSenderPort.Value);
    // Bind listener to endpoint
    sListener.Bind(listenerEndpoint);
    bwListener.RunWorkerAsync();
}
private void btnSenderStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _senderStarted = false;
    btnSenderStart.Enabled = true;
    btnSenderStop.Enabled = false;
    txtMessage.Enabled = false;
    btnSend.Enabled = false;
    txtMessage.Clear();
}
private void btnListenerStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _listenerStarted = false;
    btnListenerStart.Enabled = true;
    btnListenerStop.Enabled = false;
}
#region Listener
private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    listenerNotifier.Set();
    // Get the socket that handles the client request.
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
    // Create the state object.
    StateObject listenerState = new StateObject();
    listenerState.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(listenerState.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), listenerState);
}
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;
    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read more data.
        content = state.sb.ToString();

        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            lstListener.Items.Add(content);
        }));
    }
}
#endregion

private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtMessage.Text);
    sSender.Send(byteData);
    txtMessage.Clear();
    txtMessage.Focus();
}

private void bwListener_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    sListener.Listen(10);
     while (_listenerStarted)
    {
        // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
        listenerNotifier.Reset();
        // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
        sListener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), sListener);
        // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
        listenerNotifier.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

I can send a mesasage successfully as seen in the image. but when I try to send the second message altough it seems to send the message listener does not receive any message at all. What am I missing, or what should I fix?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initiating a subsequent receive operation. Once the first one completes, your code does not try to receive any more data. If you call `BeginReceive()` again after you're done processing a given receive operation, you should successfully read more data.

For example:

```
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;
    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read more data.
        content = state.sb.ToString();

        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            lstListener.Items.Add(content);
        }));

        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }
}
```

*(As an aside: I have seen a number of questions recently that follow a similar style to the code you're using – naming conventions, class design, logical flow, etc. – which makes me believe these are all derived from a common code example somewhere. Unfortunately, it's not really a great implementation of network I/O. I wish I knew where these examples were coming from…it'd be nice to see the original code example in context).*

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately I won't be able to try your code until I get home after work, but I will and I appreciate your effort.

Comment: About the coding style and conventions, I have several questions and answers on the site which you might hit before. But if you are spesifically  pointing the I/O code I have derived examples from MSDN examples (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx) and used the background worker just for easiness, because when I started listening, I could not start sending on the same form because the Thread UI runs on the same thread.

Comment: And just to inform, what is the common mistake you sense in coding style and what is your opinion to make it better? Regards.

Comment: @user3021830: MSDN? Wow...no kidding. I take issue with things like using the named constant instead of the actual buffer length (yes they are the same, but why ask a constant when the buffer knows its length?), the use of a `ManualResetEvent` for thread coordination, binding to an arbitrary, explicit address for the server, use of `SocketShutdown.Both` before seeing the 0-byte receive, just to name a few of the things I don't like about the example. Thanks for sharing the links.

Comment: @user3021830: by the way, you should not need to use `BackgroundWorker` at all for socket code, when you are using the asynchronous model. Indeed, this is a good example of why I object to the use of `ManualResetEvent` in the MSDN samples. The code in those samples is using the asynchronous API, but winds up effectively synchronous code anyway, negating the benefit of asynchronous I/O and obfuscating the example (i.e. the person reading it then needs to figure out what parts of the example are important to follow and what parts are contrived).

Comment: Well, actually, definind them as a constant was my temporary idea. I like to read such data from a settings file either XML, DB or other solutions, but since I am at the early stages I did not implemented it and yet, but changed the code to use a variable which will be replaced with a property which will read settings. So I could not blame MSDN for such a use :)

Comment: When I don't use BackgroundWorker `while (_listenerStarted)` loop keeps UI from responding. That's why I had to move it to another thread part from UI.

Comment: @user3021830: the MSDN samples do show the use of a `const` to define the buffer size. My issue is less with the question of a hard-coded value (vs reading config from a file), and more with that once the buffer is allocated, the code still uses the `const` and not `buffer.Length`. As far as your `while` loop, the point is that with _correct_ async I/O you don't have any explicit loops. They are implicit in the "start I/O; wait; callback for I/O complete" sequence. The MSDN samples break this by using event handles to synchronize threads, forcing explicit loops back into the code.

Comment: Sorry for tha late approval but I finally managed to sit in front of my PC. That really fixes the problem. Thank you very much for for the solution and the comments.